# How did Odin come to leave the Tesseract on Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe

The Tesseract is taken by Johann Schmidt only because he could find it on Earth. How did the Tesseract come to be on Earth?

Which explanation is correct? :

- Odin lost it during a war.
- Odin left it on Earth for (safe?)keeping.